# Variable value through method in a Java class

Tags: java, class

Consider this class:

```
public class Save extends Application {

    public int num1;
    public int count;

    public Save(int n1){
        num1=n1;
        count=1;
    }

    public int getcount()
    {
        return (count);
    }

}
```

In my main I do this:

```
 new Save(15);
 Integer result = new Save().getcount();
```

Now the value of `result` should be 1, but instead `result` is 0.

Comment: Definitely a newbie error. But don't worry your gonna get it fixed and you'll love it. Though I'm pretty certain this is a duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure how you even got this to compile as it would report that you did not pass the correct amount of arguments to the constructor, but the explanation of why (hypothetically) this occurs is as follows:

Consider your line of code:

```
Integer result = new Save().getcount();
```

Since you never give any value to `count` by never passing in an argument, it's default value is 0, because fields have default values and for integers that's 0. Also note that the line:

```
new Save(15);
```

Does nothing. It creates a new `Save` object then immediately marks it for garbage collection because there is no reference to it. You may have wanted to pass an argument for the constructor like so:

```
Integer result = new Save(SOME_NUMBER).getcount(); //result is 1
```

This will correctly call the constructor and initialize `count` to 1.

Based on your code, I assume you want `count` to become static as you want to count the amount of instances your class has:

```
public static int count;

...

public static int getCount() { //Follow Java conventions - use camelCase
    return count;
}

...

//In main
new Save(15);
Integer x = Save.getCount(); //1 instance
```

Answer (score 1):

In line 2 you're initializing a new instance of `Save` instead of using the one you previously initialized in line 1.

You can reference the previous one like so:

```
 ...
 Save mySave = new Save(15);
 Integer result = mySave.getcount();
```

Answer (score 0):

So this is your problem

```
 new Save(15);
 Integer result = new Save().getcount();
```

It should be

```
 Save save = new Save(15);
 Integer result = save.getcount();
```

Or

```
Integer result = (new Save(15)).getcount();
```

You make a new Save when you get the count which has count intialized to 0. You should be keeping an instance of your save though.

Comment: Just a tipe: Consider explaining why the answer is what it is :)

Answer (score 0):

The code as you have given won't compile. Because the Save class defines a single constructor and that takes one argument. This removes the default constructor. So the `new Save()` line would have compilation error.

My guess is, you are looking for either counting the number of time the Save object was created (in this case, count++ should be done) or you are trying to check if the Save object was created at least once (Using integer 1 as boolean true)
In either of this case, the `count` field and the `getCount()` method should be declared static. And call that method using `Save.getCount()`.

---

I have added the working code that counts the number of times the Save object is created in this [java online compiler ide - codiva](https://www.codiva.io/p/99acc755-f578-4fcd-b6cd-87b016b90a89).

---

PS: If my understanding of what you want is incorrect, please clarify the question on what you want to achieve. Also make it easy for others to help by including the code snippet in an online java ide like http://ideone.com or https://www.codiva.io

Comment: I was looking for store data in the class and check if Save object was created at least once too. So your guess is correct thanks for your explanation and code!